# Link with anchor in a b-dropdown-item with Nuxt / Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

I can't create links with anchors with `b-dropdown-item` in a `b-nav-item-dropdown`.

```html
<b-nav-item-dropdown text="Le magasin de Saint Didier" toggle-class="nav-link-dropdown" right>
  <b-dropdown-item to="/magasin-saint-didier">Le magasin</b-dropdown-item>
  <b-dropdown-item to="/magasin-saint-didier#les-horaires">Les horaires</b-dropdown-item>
  <b-dropdown-item to="/magasin-saint-didier#le-salon-de-the">Le salon de thé</b-dropdown-item>
</b-nav-item-dropdown>
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: What is not working exactly? Any errors?

Comment: Oh wait, those are hashes, try with this `:to="{ name: 'magasin-saint-didier', hash: '#les-horaires' }"` (assuming you have this `name` otherwise use `path` instead of `name`).

Comment: Hi Kissu! Thanks ;)
So your code is good, but work only if i'm not already on the page magasin-saint-didier. If it is the active page, the anchor doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [the documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/dropdown#comp-ref-b-dropdown-item-props), you can pass an object to the `to` prop.

Try using it as

```html
<b-dropdown-item :to="{ name: 'magasin-saint-didier', hash: '#les-horaires', replace: true }">Les horaires</b-dropdown-item>
```

Using [replace](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#replace) will assure that the whole thing works even if you're already on the same path.

Comment: Very curious: if i'm on TOP of the page, the anchor doesn't work...

Comment: @VinParker will maybe need a repro on this one? What do you see in your Vue devtools? Do you have some specific [scroll behavior](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#scroll-behavior) or a quick and straight follow to the hash?