# router-link VueJS can't link to an element in the same page

Tags: vue.js, routerlink, routerlinkactive, vuejs-routing

I'm trying to developp a sidebar of a documentation who it links to elements on th same page

```
      <div class="mt-6">
            <li class="relative">
              <router-link class="menuItem-active-link"  to="#users">
                 {{$t('navigation.users')}}
              </router-link>

            </li>
             <li class="relative">
              <a href="#advanced" class="menuItem-active-link" >
                {{$t('navigation.advanced')}}
              </a>
            </li>
          </div>
```

when I use the `a` tag I can navigate between each elements but I didn't know how styling the active link 
And when I use `router-link` the URL change but the page stay on the current element, it does'nt go to the specified element on `to` attribute. And with `router-link` I can styling the active link easly:

```
.router-link-exact-active.menuItem-active-link{
    background-color: cyan;
 }
```

Have you any idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: Here is how to go to another hash on the same path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72171957/8816585

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```html
<router-link :to="{ hash: '#users' }">{{ $t('navigation.users') }}</router-link>
```

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72171957/8816585).

Comment: no it is not working :(

Comment: @MAHAOUEGHLANI pretty light on what is not working.

Comment: it still on the current element even when i clicked on

Comment: Do you have a [repro] or alike? Hard to debug further here.

Comment: I can show you a small video demonstration but here it's impossible in coments

Comment: @MAHAOUEGHLANI yep, edit your question with a github repo, or a codesandbox please.